# Maven profiles issue

Tags: java, maven, maven-profiles

I'm trying to make two maven profiles, and i think I'm doing something wrong. Read on Maven website and did what was suggested, but still it not passes values  from Pom.xml to properties file
My Pom.xml:

```
<name>maven-create-profiles</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <resource.dir>src/main/resources</resource.dir>
</properties>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <properties>
            <environment>dev</environment>
            <db.username>myDevUser</db.username>
            <db.password>secretDevPasswd</db.password>
            <db.url>jdbc:mysql://localhost/myDb</db.url>
            <db.dialect>org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</db.dialect>
            <db.driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</db.driver>
        </properties>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            <property>
                <name>environment</name>
                <value>dev</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
            <environment>prod</environment>
            <db.username>myProdUser</db.username>
            <db.password>secretProdPasswd</db.password>
            <db.url>jdbc:mysql://production-database/myDb</db.url>
            <db.dialect>org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</db.dialect>
            <db.driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</db.driver>
        </properties>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>environment</name>
                <value>prod</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<build>
     <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

My properties file:

```
 db.username=${db.username}
    db.password=${db.password}
    db.url=${db.url}
    db.dialect=${db.dialect}
    db.driver=${db.driver}
```

My java class:

```
public class MyTest {

static String userName;
static String myPassword;
static String myAccount;

@BeforeClass
public void setUp() throws IOException {

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.load(new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/db.properties"));

    userName = properties.getProperty("db.username");
    myPassword = properties.getProperty("db.password");
    myAccount = properties.getProperty("db.url");
}

@Test
public void myTest() {
    System.out.println(userName);
    System.out.println(myPassword);
    System.out.println(myAccount);
}
```

}

As result after execution I'm getting:

```
     ${db.username}
     ${db.password}
     ${db.url}
```

But I actually want to get what I'm passing in maven profiles(this is main reason to make those profiles). Thank you guys in advance!!

Comment: this is insane. NEVER EVER put passwords into the POM. Use the `settings.xml` for that. By uploading your POM, you'll burn your database secrets.

Comment: You right I think it bad practice... I just saw many people do it in tutorials, so I did it too. Do you know how my Pom.xml file should changed to use settings.xml? and how settings.xml should look like to implement that? Thanks ahead

Answer (score 0):

Maven doesn't modify your sources, instead applying filtering when resources are copied to `/target`. But you shouldn't just replace `src/main/resources` with `target`. Instead, you should get final resources from classpath, e.g.:

```
properties.load(MyTest.class.getResourceAsStream("/db.properties"));
```

I recommend first making sure this works with default values without any profiles, then adding the profiles.

Comment: Thank you, worked for me. First I used target. Then I read you answer and changed like you suggested:                                                               `Properties properties = new Properties();  
        InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/db.properties");      
        properties.load(in);   
        in.close();`                           Now trying to figure it out( like one suggested in above answer) not to use my password in Pom.xml file and to use in separate properties file for security reasons